# \underline in mid-Chinese text

Tags: xecjk, underline

Using `\underline` in the middle of Chinese text adds an unexpected space. MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,asymmetric]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Scale=1,Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=.85]{SimSun}

\begin{document}

觉得\underline{对不起}父母

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: I am using

```
xeCJK.sty    2016/08/27 v3.4.1 Typesetting CJK scripts with XeLaTeX
```

I can't easily update my LaTeX installation for complicated reasons.

**Edit**: I see that using package `\CJKunderline` from package `xeCJKfntef` eliminates the problem:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,asymmetric]{article}
\listfiles

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Scale=1,Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=.85]{SimSun}

\usepackage{xeCJKfntef}

\begin{document}

觉得\CJKunderline{对不起}父母

\end{document}
```

[image]

I guess that's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my last edit, replacing `\underline` with `\CJKunderline` seems to be the solution.